# Magento 2: How to bind an element in phtml with minicart js model function?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, mini-cart

I want to print the items count in somewhere else, so i create a new phtml like this:

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
?>

<div class="test-cart" data-block="testcart">
  <span class="counter-label">
  <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
      <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko i18n: 'Item(s)' --><!-- /ko -->
  <!-- /ko -->
  </span>
  <script type="text/x-magento-init">
  {
      "[data-block='testcart']": {
          "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
      },
      "*": {
          "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= $block->escapeJs(
              $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'))
          ) ?>"
      }
  }
  </script>
</div>
```

but i always get an error like this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if:
> function(){return getCartParam('summary_count') }" Message:
> getCartParam is not defined